# Driver connection to project

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, visual-studio, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/) on how to convert a MongoDB database to a SQL Server on Azure. I cannot connect the driver to the project to pull data.

> Failure adding assembly to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name

I've already looked for other solutions to this problem on StackOverflow and they don't seem to apply to my problem. Is this guide the correct procedure to move data into the SQL Server?

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using an ODBC driver instead of the c#. I got a few weird problems regarding 32/64 bit but I made a connection for both and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) which supports [MongoDB connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb) as input and [SQL DB connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database) as output.

Please refer to this detailed [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-on-premises-mongodb-connector.md).